# Update multiple devices with one download using iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ipad, software-update, ios

I have multiple iOS devices: iPhone 5, iPad 2, 3, air.  Is it possible to use iTunes to make one download and update on all these devices?

Comment: Nope. It's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it won't download the same binary file for each device: Nope.